# Android - Is using a ViewHolder with lots of GONE and VISIBLE operation slow?

Tags: android, android-viewholder

I am developing a social media app. There are several combination of content which user can post combining text, image, video, and location.

Should I make different `ViewHolders` depending on the items which will be displayed? This would be a lot of `ViewHolders`.

Or should I make all in one `ViewHolders` for all of them? This would complicate the xml file.

Currently I am using all in one `ViewHolder` but I am concerned about the xml file, would it make the layout calculation slow?

Comment: you can use one `ViewHolder` for different xml layout files

Comment: I meant the `ViewHolder`'s xml file, it'll be filled with `Views` as I keep adding more stuffs in it, should I seperate them?